# removing specific items from an array und push them to the end

Tags: javascript, arrays

i found a javascript exercise in the internet about removing all the zeros from an array and push them to the end of that array. i've found some solutions in the internet but i didn't feel it was straight forward. My solution was :

```js
let arr = [2, 0, 5, 12, 55, 0, 8, 0, 10, 11];
let countItem = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] === 0) {
    countItem++;
  }
  if (arr[i] === 0) {
    arr.splice(i, 1);
  }
}

for(j=0; j<countItem;j++){
    arr.push(0)
}

console.log(arr);
```

who has an easier approach?

Comment: Is the mutation of the original array part of the constraint or is creating a new one acceptable?

Comment: @Peterrabbit, what solutions do you suggest? i mean both ways.

Comment: If you want to create a new array I think a filter based approach may be a more efficient algorithm, and if you want to mutate the array why not the sorting based solution I proposed, but I think the sort algorithm has more complexity than filter internally.

Comment: @Peterrabbit Yes you're right, the lads have already posted both solutions you've already mentioned!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter the zeroes then add them all back. You will know how many to add based on the difference in length of the filtered array and original.

```js
const arr = [2, 0, 5, 12, 55, 0, 8, 0, 10, 11];

const notZeroes = arr.filter((n) => n);

const result = notZeroes.concat(Array(arr.length - notZeroes.length).fill(0));

console.log(result);
```

This is similar to your solution, but removes the need for an extra variable and loop since the counter is already there as the difference in length, and the loop is "built-in" as `fill`.

Comment: thanks a lot, even easier approach thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the array filter method:

```js
let arr = [2, 0, 5, 12, 55, 0, 8, 0, 10, 11];

let final_arr = arr.filter(e => e !== 0).concat(arr.filter(e => e === 0));

console.log(final_arr);
```

So first you filter out the 0 values in the array and concat that array with the an array which only contains the 0 values

Comment: Nice work. If we wanted to go further, we can also use `e => e` and `e => !e` to check for zero and non-zero. This may be marginally slower than mine however, since you would have to loop through the entire array twice (`filter`).

Comment: oh nice approach too

Answer (score 0):

I propose this approach based on sorting  and that doesn't create a new array.

```js
let arr = [2, 0, 5, 12, 55, 0, 8, 0, 10, 11];
arr.sort((a, b) => {
    if(a === 0) return 1;
    else if (b === 0) return -1;
    else return 0;
});
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: JS ist indeed powerful, so many approaches to use! nice work

Answer (score 0):

[Insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) can be used here, maybe not the easier approach but for sure more performant than `splice` method, as it does just an [in-place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm) mutation:

```js
let arr = [2, 0, 5, 12, 55, 0, 8, 0, 10, 11];

for (let i = 1, j, n; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (j = i - 1, n = arr[i]; arr[j] === 0; j--)
        arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
    arr[j + 1] = n;
}

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: nice work.....!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Array#reduce` to create two sub arrays, non-zeros and zeros, then flatten the resulting array.

```js
const
    input = [2, 0, 5, 12, 55, 0, 8, 0, 10, 11],
    output = input.reduce(
        (acc,cur) => 
        cur === 0 ? [acc[0],[...acc[1],0]] : [[...acc[0],cur],acc[1]],
        [[],[]]
    )
    .flat();
    
console.log( output );
```

**Alternatively....**

Per @n-- (below)

```js
const
    input = [2, 0, 5, 12, 55, 0, 8, 0, 10, 11],
    output = input.reduce(
        (a,i) => (a[i === 0 ? 1 : 0].push(i), a), [[],[]]
    )
    .flat();
    
console.log( output );
```

Comment: Or just `input.reduce((a, i) => (a[i === 0 ? 1 : 0].push(i), a), [[], []]).flat()`

Comment: @PeterKA nice work ;)